# Vue 3. Как узнать цепочку вложенности компонентов друг в друга

Tags: vue.js, компоненты, spa, vue3

Мне нужно узнать цепочку вложенности компонентов Vue. Это может понадобиться для работы моего клиентского приложения. Есть ли какой-нибудь API в Vue, который позволяет это сделать?